# Getting attribute of a parent node

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parent

I am trying to use

```
$(this).parentNode.attr('data-element')
```

which should return 0 - 5 in string but it just won't work. I am using it in a function like this

```
$('.someClass').each(function(){
    $(this).html(SomeFunction('SomeString', $(this).parentNode.attr('data-element')));
});
```

All the elements with class 'someClass' have a parentNode

```
<li class="element" data-element: 1 (or any number from 0 to 5 (including))> </li>
```

and I have no idea where is the mistake. What am I doing wrong?

--David

Comment: instead of parentNode use parent() from jQuery. parentNode is from simple javascript and does not apply on jQuery elements

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You are mixing jQuery and plain javascript in the same line of code and that will not work.  You can either use:

```
$(this).parent().attr('data-element');   // jQuery
```

or

```
this.parentNode.getAttribute("data-element");   // plain javascript
```

`parentNode` is not a property of a jQuery object, so you can't mix the two the way you were doing it.  The jQuery method for getting the parent is `.parent()`.

Answer (score 4):

You should do

```
 $(this).parent().attr('data-element')
```

because you can't call `attr()` on a non jQuery object

Answer (score 3):

Try doing this instead:

```
$(this).parent().attr('data-element');
```

For more information on functions like .parent() see the Traversing section of the JQuery documentation:
http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/

Answer (score 3):

Using jquery it should be:

```
$(this).parent().attr('data-element');
```

Without using jquery this would be:

```
this.parentNode.getAttribute("data-element")
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use:

```
var item = $(this);

var parent = item.closest(".element"); //using the class for selection

//and then use parent.attr('data-element')
```